# "much less" in Russian, as in "I never imagined modelling at all, much less full-time"

Tags: словоупотребление

The adverb "особенно/especially" is used to add that something described is "all the **more** true for/if ..." in an affirmative structure:

> Конечно! **Особенно** если сможешь ...
>
> == Certainly! And **all the more so** if you ...

To express the idea of "much/still less" in a negative structure in English, on the other hand, do Russian speakers still use "особенно/especially"?

> I never imagined modelling at all, **much less** full-time.
>
> А я и не зналa, что у неe есть дочь, **особенно**{/much less} твоего возраста.

Comment: At least in English, French, Italian etc, "especially" is expressed differently, depending on whether it's in an affirmative or negative structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Тем более` is better than `особенно`.

> I never imagined modelling at all, much less full-time.
>
> Я никогда не представляла себе, что стану (буду работать, пойду работать) моделью, тем более на полную ставку.

PS: Synonom to `тем более` is `да ещё (и)` (slightly more coloquial, `и` can be omitted).  There are also colloquial variants of this: `(да) к тому же ещё (и)`, and others.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the other answer, if you're looking for a negative construction, there is

```
не говоря (уж) о..
```

> Я никогда не представляла себе, что буду моделью вообще, не говоря уж о полной ставке.

This is equivalent to the English `not to mention`